# How can i screen lines form one txt with another txt file and extract the end of the line into a completely new txt if a condition is met?

Tags: python

Thanks in advance for offering your time to read this and possibly shed some light.

I have 2 txt files:

one.txt content example:

```
a, b c { 123
d, e f { 456
u, v w { 789
x, y z { 012
```

two.txt content example:

```
a, b p
d, e p
u, v p
x, y p
```

Just a bit of context, a d u x are last names, b e v y are first names and the remaining letters are middle names.

I would like to use two.txt as the master document and screen one.txt line by line and extract the numbers on the right only if it matches with the line in two.txt. Here's the catch, I would only like to use a, b from two.txt when matching in one.txt so basically if last, first name only matches with the beginning of each line in one.txt, copy the numbers on the right of that line into a new text.

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: What have you tried?  I would suggest reading two.txt into some data structure, then using the built in startswith() and split() functions to get the rest of what you need.  The docs will be helpful in learning what those do.

Comment: You have a bevy of first names.